# How can I create an animated tile on WP7?

Tags: mobile, windows-phone-7, tile

How can I create an animated tile on WP7 similar to the XBox Live Tile? What are the options for Animating tiles in general?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a good bit of research I leaning towards it is not possible. You can use [push notification](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2010/05/03/understanding-microsoft-push-notifications-for-windows-phones/) to update the tile which does add some flexibility and opportunity but achieving the same effect as the XBox live tile is looking unlikely. With that said I do understand the motivation for the limitation if animations were available this feature would be abused and would ultimately lead to slow devices.

Answer (score 3):

In a recent Channel 9 video (about 11 minutes in) the softie presenters say this requires Microsoft "special sauce", e.g. this feature is not available to non Microsoft developers. I am guessing (only a guess!) that they will eventually open this feature. The link is here: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/This+Week+On+Channel+9/TWC9-mvcConf-WP7-Tools-update-AsmSpy-JavaScript-OO